# Filtering array by only false values of a specific key, value pair

Tags: javascript

I have a an array of objects that looks something like this:

```
[
    {id: 1, isValid: true, name: "something1", pdpEnabled: false},
    {id: 2, isValid: false, name: "something2", pdpEnabled: false}
]
```

I am trying to filter out all the objects that contain isValid: false. I am unsure of how to go about this when the objects contain other key value pairs that also contain the value of false for pdpEnabled.  Is there a way to filter by a specific key value pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just search for that key for which the value is false (isValid: false), no need to worry about other keys

```js
const input = [{
  id: 1,
  isValid: true,
  name: "something1",
  pdpEnabled: false,
},
{
  id: 2,
  isValid: false,
  name: "something2",
  pdpEnabled: false
}
];


const result = input.filter(x => !x.isValid)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: `to filter out...` ;)

Comment: filter in, filter out, i believe this is the needed solution as per the above comment of the op itself

Answer (score 1):

```
const newArray=[
    {id: 1, isValid: true, name: "something1, pdpEnabled: false"},
    {id: 2, isValid: false, name: "something2, pdpEnabled: false}
].filter(item=>item.isValid===true);
```

Comment: .filter(item=>!item.isValid)